# UIView moves down when Assigning Value to UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I'm making an app that moves the view (when iPone 4s/5/5c/5s) up when the keyboard is shown. however, when i type something using the number pa, it triggers the view to go back down. The code for `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` changes the text and then assigns it back to the textbook.

```
- (BOOL)  textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

NSString* totalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
if(textField.tag==102) {
    if (([textField.text isEqualToString:@"0"]) && (textField.text.length == 1)) {
        textField.text = @"";
        NSLog(@"Zero Encountered");
        return NO;
    }
    if (range.length == 1) {
        // Delete button was hit.. so tell the method to delete the last char.
        textField.text = [_iOSApiService_model formatPhoneNumber:totalString deleteLastChar:YES];
    } else {
        textField.text = [_iOSApiService_model formatPhoneNumber:totalString deleteLastChar:NO];
    }
    return YES;
}
return YES;
}

-(void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification {
//The keyboard was shown, move movableView objects UP
NSLog(@"value of _keyboardshownUp is %i",_keyboardshownUp);
if (_keyboardshownUp == 1) {
    //Keyboard was already shown
} else {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    //This will move the frame back to place

    _movableView.frame = CGRectMake(_movableView.frame.origin.x,
                                    _movableView.frame.origin.y+_variableMove,
                                    _movableView.frame.size.width,
                                    _movableView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"Move View up");
    _keyboardshownUp = 1;
}
}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
//The keyboard was shown, move movableView objects down

NSLog(@"value of _keyboardshownUp is %i",_keyboardshownUp);
if (_keyboardshownUp == 0) {
    //Keyboard was already hiden
} else {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    //This will move the frame back to place
    _movableView.frame = CGRectMake(_movableView.frame.origin.x,
                                    _movableView.frame.origin.y-_variableMove,
                                    _movableView.frame.size.width,
                                    _movableView.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"Move View Down");
    _keyboardshownUp = 0;
}
}
```

I'm doing this in conjunction with `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`. If i disable the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString` then there is no problem. but, the moment I assign a value to the "issue" `UITextField`, as if the keyboard was hidden (even though it is not) and the Main `UIView` reverts back to its orig position thus the Keyboard obscures the view. PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently i have facing these sort of problem too much, thats why i'm creating a library to face this situation. Take a look at [KeyboardAnimator](https://github.com/ratulSharker/Keyboard-Animator). Hope it met your requirement.

Comment: this is a nice thing :) the issue is that the moment shouldChangeCharactersInRange assigns a value to the text field textField.text, it brings down the view which then prevents the textbox from being visible to the user. does your example eliminate this? haven't had the chance to check it though :) BUT THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH!

Comment: I'm animating the view to downside only when the keyboard disappear. Is that what u want ? in keyboard animator no textfield delegate is set to the main library.

Comment: in my code, if i remove the textfield.text = , I do not encounter the issue of the view going down. the moment i change the value of the object, it somehow triggers the change. I'm also perplexed with that

Comment: when you set the textField's text value using textField.text does this log `value of _keyboardshownUp is %i` shows in the output & please share the initial value of the  `keyboardshownUp` & `_variableMove`

Comment: will do! I will update once Im back. Thank you for the clear path :)

Comment: I just checked and WTFudge!!! you are a genius!!!! This is just what I need and want!!! Bingo~!~!~!

Answer (score 0):

To moves your UI controller, when assigning value to UITextField use the  "[IQKeybordManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager.git)" a library to solved this situation.
IQKeybordManager ran into an issues where the iPhone keyboard slide up and cover the UITextField/UITextView. IQKeyboardManager allows you to prevent issues of the keyboard sliding up and cover UITextField/UITextView without needing you to enter any code and no additional setup required. To use IQKeyboardManager you simply need to add source files to your project.